# What do I need to setup SDL2 in a 64bit computer?

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw, 64-bit, sdl-2

My goal is to setup SDL2 environment with vscode. I failed when trying to make a executable file in 64-bits.

However, after I changed those SDL2 libraries, header files and dll to 32-bit version, I succeeded and made a 32-bit executable file.

For your references, followings are my workspace directories:

```
>SDL2
  >src
    >include  (SDL2 header files)
    >lib      (SDL2 lib)
  >main.cpp
  >Makefile
```

Makefile:

```
all:
    g++ main.cpp -I src/include -L src/lib -o main -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

Complains:

```
PS D:\vscode\SDL2> make
g++ main.cpp -I src/include -L src/lib -o main -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccg3PdH7.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccg3PdH7.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x43): undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccg3PdH7.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x51): undefined reference to `SDL_GetError'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccg3PdH7.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x96): undefined reference to `SDL_PollEvent'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccg3PdH7.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xb7): undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyWindow'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\ccg3PdH7.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xbc): undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 1
```

I guess the problem is that I probably use a wrong toolchain(32bit mingw).
I will also be grateful if someone can help me check my toolchain.

Comment: Did you try not using the 32-bit flag for your desired 64 bit executable? It's simple enough to try.

Comment: Do you have 64-bit builds of the libraries?

Comment: You just need a 64-bit MinGW. [Get it from MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075). I would replace the 32-bit one too, yours is outdated (6.x vs 12.x).